# Angular JS - HTTP Web Server

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I am very new to Angular JS. I need a local http web server to run my application made in Angular JS.

Is it necessary to use Node JS or can i use any other local http web server i.e. Xammplite, Wampp etc.

Please let me know.

Comment: node js is not necessary, you can use any backend to work with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS is a frontend framework, so it is independent of the implementation of the server.  You can use Node.JS or any local http web server that you are comfortable with to host your site.

Comment: Can i use Xampplite (https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html) in order to host/deploy my application on my local windows machine ?

Comment: Yeah, you can definitely use it

Answer (score 1):

You can use Apache Tomcat Server and can put your project in webapps folder of Tomcat.

Then after start the Tomcat server your application will be deployed on http server.

It is necessary becuase suppose we are  making call to some javascript file through the http method like

```
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js"></script>
```

then you need http server.

You can achieve the same through Apache Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

node.js is not necessary, you can use any backend server to do CRUD operations. you will have to use $http to communicate with you backend server.